# Visual Studio Code - jump cursor to current selection (find mode)

Tags: visual-studio-code

let's say I need to find a word.. I press (on mac) **CMD+F** e start typing. Then it finds all the occurrences highlighting one.

How do I jump the cursor mouse to that match?

If there is only 1 word I could press **ALT + ENTER** but if there are more, then it selects all the occurrences so I have to press **ESC** twice to have the cursor where I wanted.

or there is another way of **goto** word in document?

Comment: No, I think hitting ESC twice is the best you can do.  You can F3 to the occurrence you want to jump to, ESC once and your cursor is there with that word selected, ESC again to unselect that word.  I think this is what you are already doing - it seems pretty straightforward.  Also see this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mksafi.find-word-at-cursor

Comment: yes it is pretty straightforward but when you have a lot of words of the same name and you select everything just to deselect everything, it just feels like the wrong way of doing it. there are so many hidden shortcuts in vscode that you never know. but actually the extension is pretty nice thanks for sharing!